# Where is the command line for Microsoft Windows?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I'm trying to create my first YII application, and I have a problem. Look here:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app

In this part:
Run `yiic` on the command line as follows:

```
% YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp WebRoot/testdrive
```

Where should I type this row? I aleady try to search answers like here:
[how to create webapp with yiic command using Yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767326/how-to-create-webapp-with-yiic-command-using-yii-framework)

But this didnot helped me.
My system is windows 7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can write this in the cmd: Windows + R -> cmd

Comment: @Dinistro I already try to use the cmd, i get an error that "%" is not exits..

Comment: @Dinistro i already tried it, not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find a shell in:

```
Start / All Programs / Accessories / Windows PowerShell
```

Alternatively, you can just search the *Search programs and files* option in the Start menu.

You will need to change directory (with the `cd` command) to the place where you have put the `YiiRoot` directory.

Note that `%` indicates the prompt, and is not a character you should type yourself.

Comment: I visited the PowerShell, and got a problem. the path start from:
PS C:\Users\win7> and my wamp server is in C:\wamp\YII, I dont know how to fix the path in the PowerShell, please help

Comment: Thanks, I founded the correct path:
PS C:\wamp> www/YII/framework/yiic webapp www/testdrive

:)